# accessibility.sty not found

Tags: packages, accessibility

I am using the accessibility package via `\usepackage[tagged]{accessibility}`. However, when I compile my document with XeLaTeX and Texstudio I receive the error `File 'accessibility.sty not found'`.

Comment: That probably means that you didn't install it. Use the miktex console or the texlive manager depending on your tex system. But the package will not work with xelatex, only with pdflatex.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I switch to pdflatex I receive errors regarding fontspec. Hm. I will still try to install it via the miktex soncole.

Comment: you could try the tagpdf package with lualatex. But be warned: it is experimental, so read the documentation.

Comment: I appreciate your work on tagpdf. However, reading the hints on the first page of the documentations scares me off a bit since I consider myself rather a beginner :(

Comment: Unfortunately if I apply `\usepackage{tagpdf}` it says `Package tagpdf Error: xelatex is not supported - aborting. }`. However, I rely on XeLaTeX to use `fontspec` for Calibri.

Comment: Use lualatex, it can be used with fontspec too.

Comment: Beside this: if you are a beginner you shouldn't try to use a package like accessibility. It is basically not working, you only need to look at the issue list, e.g. https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues/34 or https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues/12. tagpdf may be experimental and more difficult to use but at least it works - and I do have a clue what /StructParents is meant to do.

Comment: I am struggling a bit with tagpdf and posted a (support-request) issue on GitLab. Maybe this could also be a nice proof-of-concep of `tagpdf`. However, I am running a bit out of time. I hope I will find some time tonight or tomorrow to look at it again :)

Comment: Yes, ignore `accessibility` at this point (I'm the maintainer). @UlrikeFischer thanks for pointing out that there are challenges there. If you have ideas on how to fix them, maybe we could talk in the chat?

Comment: @AndyClifton sure you can always come into the chat.